# Angular Material intentions and hues used by components

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, theming

I am trying to use angular material,

I read everything in the [documentation's theming section](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/01_introduction) revied most of the demos and directive docs and even tried to have a look into the source code and I was wandering if there is a guide somewhere that explains how each angular material ui directive uses the different intention palettes and hues set in a theme.

The reason I am asking for this is that it feels like as long as we choose standard palettes everything plays nice but the moment we want to make any change we are blind as to the implications.

(e.g. how to prevent a situation where you choose a background color the ends up being the same color as some accent color used for example as the underline color for a textbox causing the undeline not to be visible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one part in the mentioned documentation that comes to mind.

> **Specifying Custom Hues For Color Intentions**
>
> You can specify the hues from a palette that will be used by an intention group by default and for the md-hue-1, md-hue-2, md-hue-3 classes.
>
> By default, shades 500, 300 800 and A100 are used for primary and warn intentions, while A200, A100, A400 and A700 are used for accent.

You can check the hues/shades used by each component in the source. There is a `*-theme.scss` file for each component: https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/input/input-theme.scss

And there is the official material design style guide, telling you which hues/shades are used for what.
https://material.google.com/style/color.html#color-color-palette

Comment: yes, I was able to find the *-them.scss files and they are indeed helpful to some degree.
I was hoping for some cheetsheet / summary of the information stored in those scss files...

Comment: what is default value of md-hue-1/2/3 any idea ?